# Downloading Ubuntu Server for x86 Architecture

Tags: installation, downloads

I can't seem to find the x86 64 bit download for Ubuntu Server 12.04. I am taken to a download page easily enough, but the download file is confusingly named "ubuntu- 12.04-server-amd64.iso.crdownload.

Does this contain the x86 installation or do I need another ISO I can't find?

Comment: That is the 64 bit ISO.

Comment: Yeah I need a 64 bit ISO but for the Intel architecture. I can't find it, the defualt download is for AMD64. I assume for AMD CPU's

Comment: See the link I gave you, the "amd" iso is for x86 and is 64 bit